# Alignment Of Header Elements Is Off

Tags: theme, search, header

This is a pretty basic CSS question I think, but I'm struggling to solve it.

I recently updated my theme (Ultimo) and it seems as though my custom sub-theme is overriding some default CSS that justifies the search bar true left. My header is based on a grid structure (i.e. 12 columns therefore header is three columns of 12-4 12-4 12-4). I think it may be a problem with the left hp-block.

Demo: http://bear15.livesol.net

Any help would be appreciated.

p.s. this is my first request on here, so apologies if there's a lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the centered class from the navbar:

[image]

Alternatively you can edit `/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/infortis/ultra-megamenu/menu.css` on  `line 247` and remove the `text-align:center` for selector `.nav-regular.centered`:

[image]

Comment: Using the ultimo theme I suspect it's possible to do this somewhere in the settings by the way

Comment: It's only the search wrapper I need to justify left. Everything else is good where it is. I set the search position to primary left in settings, which was fine until I updated to Ultimo 1.14. Even if I disable the centred nav to have it justify left again, the search wrapper stays where it is.

Comment: I just toggled with turning the grid12-4 width class on and off and that solved the problem. However, it applied those changes to elements with the same class across the board of course.